# xcode4 with SDK 4.3 App working in sim but crashes on device, how is that possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm testing my app in the sim with SDK 4.3, My device is iPhone 4 with OS 4.3.3, when running the app on the sim every things is working, no errors and nothing, but on the device every thing crashes with the runtime error: **"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key addButton"**

I can not find the problem in any xib file. I used to have this outlet, but not any more, not in the class and not in the xib (or maybe i am missing it, but i looked of many many hours for it) and the sim is getting it that i have changed the files but the device does not...

**UPDATE:** **maybe this would help. I decided to test my theory and removed (deleted) the MainWindox.xib file. compiled and got the same results...On the sim every things worked (WIERD AS IS) and in the device crashes.... The first part tells me that when the Xcode does the link and build, It builds from a deferent directory then the one that the project in... It is as weird as it can get in my eyes.... Any one has a thought about that? I think that when i will fix this every thing else will work just fine....**

What can i do?

Thank you very much,
Erez

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check the capitalisation of all your view controllers (case sensitivity). Also check your outlet casing.

Comment: 10x, Is the sim not case sensitive ???

Comment: can you paste the code which is in your application disfinishlaunching block? I have faced the same problem

Comment: Sachim, did you mean the didFinishLaunching in the appDelegate file? that is the only place there is one... not in the file that is causing the problem, and there is only two lines over there, connecting the tabRootController to the window and displaying the window. I think that what is happening is that the device might be using the old version somehow, I just can't find addButton any more in the code (and it shouldn't be there) that is the weird part.... thank :-)

Comment: @Erez - No, the sim is NOT case sensitive.  There are a few differences between the simulator and the real devices - that's why they call it a simulator and not an emulator.  And this is why they always advise to test on a real device!

Comment: It is great that they tell you to test on actual device, but I just think what would people say about Eclipse or Visual studio of a program they developed worked in there and then not working on the device.... And This problem is so weird, If it would have be trivial ,that i forgot the IBOutlet or something like that, I would have kicked my self and go on, but I didn't forget to take it of... In all my project there is no addButton (NO WHERE) and still getting this error on the device..... And i just can't go on now.... Don't know what to do, and this project has so many hours of work/files..

Comment: @Erez - There are significant differences in hardware between a desktop computer and a mobile device, from CPU to GPU to touchscreen input.  Of course there will be differences when you run an application built for the mobile device vs. the simulator.  Many memory and performance issues will only appear when running on the contrained hardware of the mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the problem was exactly what i said, The XCode went to a wrong build somewhere, I don't know where and what happen, but it didn't go to the new build.... created a new project, copied all the files and then just changed the delegate and what needed and every thing is working, I am guessing it is a BUG, a very annoying one, but still a bug with XCode 4.

Thank you all,
Erez

Answer (score 2):

There would most probably be a viewcontroller name just above the above error. Open the xib of that viewcontroller and check all buttons in that xib, and check the outlets of each of them. I assume you have forget to remove the outlet connection from one of the buttons.

If you cannot spot out the viewcontroller that has the problem, you need to check all xib files. Also, as alexJones mentioned, please check the capitalization of outlets as the device is case sensitive where the simulator is not.

Comment: THank you, but I did that all ready, I've checked all XIB files, in xcode and in xdash for this addButton outlet, it is not there any more, nor in any XIBs and not in the class that was mentioned over there (You don't see the class name because it is in angular brackets and I guess the system removed it.... but i've checked and checked again, it is like the sim and the compilation for the device use deferent files....I'm probably wrong, just look like it....), so annoying that things work on the sim and then this....this is so bad... :-(

Comment: please confirm that you are not using multiple versions of the same xib file. Check your project folder for all files that have the name same as your xib, without using the extension so that you should see only 3 files, 1 each of .h, .m and .xib.

Comment: Well Nithin, Thank you again, The problem is not over there also, I don't have 3 files for every thing, There some that don't have XIB and other things, But There are no files that has more the 3 files (1 for each).... As i said, it is like the Xcode is trying to read from a deferent path when compiling and linking for the device, and maybe there are old files over there that has the addButton outlet, I don't know what to say, Thank you.....

Answer (score 1):

You might had an outlet "addButton" connected to a button in XIB.
Later you might have removed "addButton" from code, but forgot to remove the connection in XIB.
If you open XIB, right click the "File's owner", you can see "addButton" in red color. Click "x" button to remove it. Then build the code and run on your iphone. It must work now.

Also clean your code, remove the app from your device before running on the device.

Comment: Thank you, and again, NO, I had it before, and I took it of, Changed the concept for the app and then, when finished saw that every thing is working on the sim but not on the device.... I've all ready did that, and this is not the answer in my case :-( thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Before going to such extremes as copying your project ... try cleaning your target sim and device first, then building from scratch. In effect i believe that is what you achieved by creating a new project.

Comment: Thank you, but i tried cleaning before copying the project, in my case it didn't help..... I just don't know why, I agree with you that it should have worked....But still, it didn't.... In any case, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, would build and execute in the simulator but crash on my iPhone.  The solution turned out to be improper case of a nib name in interface builder.  detailView instead of the actual nib name DetailView.  Great advice, thanks!